# Modal dialog under the backdrop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-modal

I am using Bootstrap 5 and modal is kinda tricky. Do you happen to know why the dialog is under the backdrop? I've compared the modal example on Bootstrap website and on my code. I haven't changed any positions, just added header color and adjusted padding.

One solution would be using `data-bs-backdrop="false"` but I wanted to have a backdrop. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: This is more of a CSS question. Check the console, play around with z-index, check if your own styles somehow targeted the bootstrap classes.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, I'll check. So far I haven't found the culprit.